# Using Eliptical Curve Cryptography with OpenSSL for php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, openssl

I am trying to find some documentation on using Elliptical Curve Cryptography in php with openssl and I can't seem to find anything.  I would prefer not to import a library if openssl does it just fine.

I found this:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-curve-names.php

But it gives no context on how to use these curves.  I am wanting a simple example that simply uses a public key to encrypt some data.  Then decrypts the private key with a passphrase, and proceeds to decrypt the data.  I am wanting to be able to use the encrypted data with a ECC compatible javascript library too. I found this one: https://github.com/indutny/elliptic/  But it seems to only sign and not encrypt.

I also found this which seemed nice:
https://github.com/keybase/kbpgp

But it seems to require subkeys instead of just a standard key, which seems really counter intuitive.  I tried creating just a normal key without a subkey and it failed.

I have googled quite a bit and couldn't seem to find any solid examples.
Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need to use Elliptic-curve cryptography instead of encryption based on non-elliptic-curve groups?

Comment: @Mike It seems like everything that I have read says that standard RSA encryption seems to be becoming more and more vulnerable to attacks, like index calculus attacks.  I would like this piece of software to hopefully stay relevant because it will probably be around for ten+ years.  I guess I haven't really heard much about AES attacks, but I want to use public and private keys.

Comment: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Elliptic_Curve_Operations

Answer (score 1):

ECC can only be used for encryption if you're using it in as part of a hybrid cryptosystem. eg. Ephemeral Key ECDH.

OpenSSL (well, more specifically, PHP's bindings to OpenSSL) does not support this:

[does OpenSSL support ECDH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222220/does-openssl-support-ecdh)

libsodium, however, does, with Curve25519. eg. `sodium_crypto_box` and `sodium_crypto_box_open`:

https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/05-publickey-crypto.md#crypto-box

The specific algorithms it implements are as follows:

- Key exchange: X25519
- Encryption: XSalsa20 stream cipher
- Authentication: Poly1305 MAC

Comment: Well, actually one can use [ECC for encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/45042/18298), too. Also, see [ECIES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51203/18298).